# Random dice roll

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript and I'm creating a game of dice. I want to make a Javascript function which the dice appear random, and i want change dice randomly in every click on button.
This is the javascript and html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Lancio del dado</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var numero_dado = 1;
var tempo =1000;
setTimeout(function(){lancio_dado(); }, tempo);
</script>
<style>
table{
 *border-collapse: collapse; /* IE7 and lower */
  border-spacing: 0;  
 background:#ffffff !important; /* For IE*/ 
}
.bordered {
  border: solid #ccc 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
 behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc; 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc; 
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;         
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function lancio_dado(){
 if(numero_dado == 1){
  document.getElementById('primacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('secondacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('terzacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('quartacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('quintacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('sestacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('settimacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('ottavacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('nonacella').innerHTML = "";
  numero_dado = 2;
  setTimeout(function(){lancio_dado(); }, tempo);
  breake();
 }
 if(numero_dado == 2){
  document.getElementById('primacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('secondacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('terzacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('quartacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('quintacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('sestacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('settimacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('ottavacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('nonacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  numero_dado = 3;
   setTimeout(function(){lancio_dado(); }, tempo);
   breake();
 }
 if(numero_dado == 3){
  document.getElementById('primacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('secondacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('terzacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('quartacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('quintacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('sestacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('settimacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('ottavacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('nonacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  numero_dado = 4;
   setTimeout(function(){lancio_dado(); }, tempo);
   breake();
 }
 if(numero_dado == 4){
  document.getElementById('primacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('secondacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('terzacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('quartacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('quintacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('sestacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('settimacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('ottavacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('nonacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  numero_dado = 5;
   setTimeout(function(){lancio_dado(); }, tempo);
   breake();
 }
 if(numero_dado == 5){
  document.getElementById('primacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('secondacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('terzacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('quartacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('quintacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('sestacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('settimacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('ottavacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('nonacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  numero_dado = 6;
   setTimeout(function(){lancio_dado(); }, tempo);
   breake();
  
 }
 if(numero_dado == 6){
  document.getElementById('primacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('secondacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('terzacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('quartacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('quintacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('sestacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('settimacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  document.getElementById('ottavacella').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('nonacella').innerHTML = "<img src='./img/punto.jpg'  width='50' height='50'>";
  numero_dado = 1;
   setTimeout(function(){lancio_dado(); }, tempo);
   breake();
  
 }
}
</script>
</script>
<button onclick="throwdice">Lancia il dado</button>
<center>
<table  class= "bordered" width ="300" height="300">
 <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100" height="100"><span id="primacella"></span></td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100" height="100"><span id="secondacella"></span></td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100" height="100"><span id="terzacella"></span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100" height="100"><span id="quartacella"></span></td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100" height="100"><span id="quintacella"></span></td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100" height="100"><span id="sestacella"></span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100" height="100"><span id="settimacella"></span></td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100" height="100"><span id="ottavacella"></span></td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100" height="100"><span id="nonacella"></span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, great, so what's your question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
numero_dado = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
```

This statement generates a random number in the range [1,6] and assign it to numero_dado.